# mongoose returning Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following error on my express app which tells me that I haven't registered my schema but infact that I have already done that.

```
 /home/work/dashboard/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Devices".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (/home/work/dashboard/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/work/dashboard/server/services/devices.js:6:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at normalLoader (/home/work/dashboard/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/work/dashboard/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/work/dashboard/server/routes/index.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at normalLoader (/home/work/dashboard/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/work/dashboard/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

This is what my model looks like

```
   import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Devices = new Schema({

    userName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    devices: [{
        gatwayId: String,
        type: String
    }]
}, {
    collection: 'devices'
});

Devices = mongoose.model('Devices', Devices);

export default Devices;
```

and here is the service that is supposed to call the model.

```
 'use strict';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import _ from 'lodash';

var deviceModel = mongoose.model('Devices');
```

An finally this is how it looks like on the main index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import cors from 'cors';
import api from './routes';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import fs from 'fs';
import join from 'join';

dotenv.config();

var app = express();

app.server = http.createServer(app);

app.db = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URL);

app.db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'mongoose connection error: '));

app.db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('connected to the mongoose database');
});


// Bootstrap models
fs.readdirSync(join(__dirname, 'models')).forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(join(__dirname, 'models', file));
});


// 3rd party middleware
app.use(cors({
    exposedHeaders: ['Link']
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(logger('dev'));

// api router
app.use('/api', api);

app.server.listen(process.env.PORT || 6000);

console.log(`Started on port ${app.server.address().port}`);

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `import` your file where you define the model somewhere. So somewhere in your code do.

```
import Device from './path/to/your/model/file'
```

Comment: @bazinga: be aware that Mongoose is a bit picky about registering models twice. It may be a good thing to ensure the `mongoose.mode(name, schema)` is only called once.

Comment: How are you able to use import - I thought inport wasn't working in node yet?

Comment: My guess would be that some sort of compiling was in place (babel or traceur).